# clusterProfiler, groupGO: meaning of GeneRatio

Tags: rna-seq, groupgo, clusterprofiler

I am running `groupGO` function from `clusterProfiler`:

```
ggo <- groupGO(gene     = head(gene, 200),
           OrgDb    = org.Mm.eg.db,
           keyType = "ENSEMBL",
           ont      = "BP",
           level    = 2,
           readable = TRUE)
```

And getting the following output:

```
> head(ggo)
                   ID            Description Count GeneRatio
GO:0000003 GO:0000003           reproduction     5     5/200
GO:0008152 GO:0008152      metabolic process    40    40/200
GO:0001906 GO:0001906           cell killing     0     0/200
GO:0002376 GO:0002376  immune system process    20    20/200
GO:0006791 GO:0006791     sulfur utilization     0     0/200
GO:0006794 GO:0006794 phosphorus utilization     0     0/200
```

As can be seen `cell killing`, `sulfur utilization` and `phosphorus utilization` have `zero` genes. Then, why are they here at all? Should not the `groupGO` show only `biological processes` the fed in genes are related to? This seems very weird to me. What is the meaning of the `GeneRatio` column?

Comment: If you don't want terms with zero genes, just use `ggo[ggo$Count>0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to be learning, the clusterProfiler package is a bit "special". It doesn't filter the results you're seeing for relevance, it returns everything. The `GeneRatio` is the number of genes in your input list associated with the given GO term (e.g., `5`) and then a `/` and the total number of input genes. This is generally not that useful. Since many things aren't documented, you may find [the source code](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/clusterProfiler/blob/6352683788121b8ff1a3dde3312fbe096e3f9f52/R/groupGO.R#L43-L55) helpful.